# SSH to EC2 on an iphone using mobile internet and restrictive Security Groups

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, vpn

I will soon only have access to my Iphone (holidays) to connect to the internet. I need at least to be able to connect via SSH to my EC2 servers from an Iphone and a dynamic IP.

Also, I am not allowed to change the current security groups for these servers (except maybe to connect to another server of our AWS) and they are very restrictive.

I couldn't find a way to change the security for dynamic IP from an Iphone.

I was thinking of creating a small machine with a less restrictive security group, install a VPN on it, use OpenVPN on my Iphone and forward the traffic the other server then.. but I don't know if I'm going the wrong way or if there is an easier one.

Any idea?

Comment: Your OpenVPN idea is probably the best solution, given the security group restrictions.

Comment: Where can you currently access your EC2 servers from? Presumably you can do it from your office - if your office is accessible from the outside world then what about an ssh hop through there?

Comment: So basically, the EC2 instance only allow SSH from the static IP of the office. Additionnaly, the VPN is very much blocked and regulated and I can't reach the EC2 using it for instance (!). So it looks like Marc B is right